# Why do I get "The constructor Intent(Class<LivrmStartActivity>) is undefined" message?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I declared an intent which will go to the next activity. But I get an error message saying that the constructor intent is undefined. Thank you to anybody who can tell how to fix this.

```
                              if (i < badsprite) {
                              score++;
                              badsprite--;
                                    sounds.play(sndSquish, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0  , 0, 1.5f);
                              } else{
                              life--;

                                  sounds.play(sndOuch, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.5f);
                              }
                                sprites.remove(sprite);
                                temps.add(new PorchTempSprite(temps, this, x, y, bmpSlime));
                           if (badsprite == 0){

Intent m = new Intent(LivrmStartActivity.class); //Where the error is
                               startActivity(m); //And here too



                           }

                                break;
                          }
                   } 
            }
     }
return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because there is no such constructor. Assuming that the rest of your code is correct, use `new Intent(this, LivrmStartActivity.class)` instead.